# Spotlight indexes wrong HD

Tags: spotlight

Mac Mini Server, OSX Server 10.6.8, dual drive

I cloned the first hard disk (HD1) to HD2 using CCC, thus creating a bootable copy.
However, now I discover that when I startup from HD2, Spotlight has been indexing only HD1.

Using a Terminal command to rebuild the Spotlight index doesn't help. 
I get the message for HD2: There is no index.
Using the option for all volumes, it only rebuilds for HD1.

This problem is nasty, as I intend to use an Automator script that filters files, and for this it uses Spotlight (I get an error now).

Any ideas how to bring OSX to build an index for HD2?

Comment: Have you tried using disk utility to unmount and repair both volumes in the same session? You might need to modify the partition map (resize and the resize back) to re-establish the volumes as unique.

Answer (score 1):

`mdutil -s /Volumes/*` will show you the indexing status of all available volumes.

`mdutil -i on /Volumes/HD2;mdutil -i off /Volumes/HD1` should do what you're asking for.  might need to sudo based on ownership settings of each.

Answer (score 1):

Try this add HD1 and HD2 to the Privacy tab in Spotlight System Preferences panel. Then Remove HD2, and HD2 should rebuild. See [Spotlight: How to re-index folders or volumes](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2409).