# Mac App Store thinks I don't have any apps installed

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

Okay, I have the weirdest problem. All the apps in my 'Purchases' tab show either 'Install' or 'Download', most of the apps I currently have installed, but non the less it doesn't recognise them. This holds true for brand new apps (installed yesterday) and ones I've had since I installed ML. I'd really like to get the apps recognised, so that I can get updates for them.

I've scoured the internet far and wide and haven't even been able to find any similar problems.

I really wish someone has an answer :)

Update:
Deleting and reinstalling an app has no effect. It shows installed at first, but switching tabs and coming back to 'Purchases' renders it back to 'Install'.

Update:
`CKSoftwareMap: updateRequestBodyData:includeInstalledApps:includeBundledApps:conditionally:hadUnadoptedApps:waitUntilMapIsLoaded: timed out waiting for mdSemaphore``

This is the "culprit" from Console.app and seems to be dependent on Spotlight indexes. Still don't know what corrupts my spotlight indexes...

Comment: Did you move the app from the application folder?

Comment: Nope, all my app's are in the application folder. And it's not really an app, it's all apps which I have "purchased"

Comment: Have you tried deleting an app and redownloading it to see if it fixes it? Also try this suggestion, http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20028985-263.html

Comment: @Tony Too bad none of the methods in your link helped :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to focus on problems with either Spotlight finding the apps or perhaps an overall disk structure failure.

- [Spotlight: How to re-index folders or volumes - HT2409](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2409)
- [Spotlight indexes wrong HD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33062/spotlight-indexes-wrong-hd)
- [Using Disk Utility to verify or repair disks - HT1782](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1782)

Unless you are going in and systematically [modifying each app's receipt](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69821/how-can-i-change-an-app-purchased-from-the-app-store-so-that-i-dont-get-updates), the App Store should find apps using spotlight and correctly reflect the status assuming both the disk doesn't need repair and the spotlight index is current.

Comment: Okay, I found another post that points to the Spotlight indexes (http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/279751-app-store-broken/). So now I'm waiting for the re-indexing to finish (3h to go...)

Comment: If you're impatient, you can exclude all user home folders by adding /Users to the privacy pane - the system should be able to index the core files in less than 30 minutes. You'll still need to wait hours for the bulk of the drive to pass through the data detectors, but at least your irritation will be solved or we'll have eliminated the likely culprit.

Comment: I haven't been feeling impatient, so I still got 20 mins left. I've been noticing my Console.app cluttering up with errors messages from spotlight. `mds[36]: (Error) Task: Can't init <MDSClient 0x7f8eb68d6e70 shutdown:NO got shutdown notification:NO> -- too many objects for MDSTaskRegistry` and `mdworker[3995]: (Warning) Worker: Unable to fetch debug levels from server.  Continuing with default debug levels.  (268435459: (ipc/send) invalid destination port)`

Comment: Grr - those often mean there's a problem with one of the data importers or a file causing spotlight to bomb out. We're straying into "diagnosing spotlight" and I'll just point out that `mddiagnose` is a nice tool to collect tons of logs, and trial/error can often point out where in the directory tree Spotlight gives up - sometimes a problem with one file prevents others from being scanned.

Comment: As we already suspected, the rebuilding of indexes and disk repair (nothing to repair) and disk permissions had absolutely no effect. Trying to wade through `mddiagnose` logs and maybe spot something...

Comment: Hmm, something really weird came up. Running `mdutil -s /Volumes/*` tells me `Spotlight server is disabled.``

Comment: Umm, I don't know what happened. I unloaded and loaded mds in launchctl and suddenly everything works again.... I'll accept your answer since It seems to be the culprit.

Comment: damnit... app store forgot all about my apps again :(

Comment: Spotlight problems often can be temporarily avoided when you force a rebuild, but my experience is they come back in time until the bad file / folder / filesystem gets fixed or deleted. :( Sorry I don't have a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to the possible solutions… I had the same problem.  Turns out I also had a Windows disk installed that I needed some files from.  I kept seeing errors in system.log like "Error getting quotas for volume /Volumes/...".

I powered off, disconnected the Windows disk, and rebooted.  Voila!  App Store can now search for updates and identifies installed purchases under the "Purchases" tab.

I hope I can save someone time, this problem has been plaguing me for a few days now.